# gmaps4rails enable clustering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How can I enable clustering so instead of showing markers it is clustered? For example: https://www.police.uk/metropolitan/00BK17N/crime/

users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
      marker.lat user.latitude
      marker.lng user.longitude
      marker.infowindow user.description
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="map-container">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map-canvas'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>)
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds(markers);
    if(navigator.geolocation)
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition;
  });
});
</script>
```

Appreciate your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? 
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers#displaying-your-markers

Simply passing do_clustering => true should enable it. It's false by default.
Example:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => { "data" => @markers, "options" => { "do_clustering" => true } }) %>
```

Comment: i get undefined method `gmaps' for #<#<Class:0x007ff7b8af3270>:0x007ff7b929a898>